# Accepting zero as a value

Tags: php, sql

I have a form, and one input is amount. I want to be able to use 0 as a price, but if I use zero, I get an error as set by me that I cannot leave the input blank.

The field is set as int(10).

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Post your code for validating the field. You may want to use `!==''` or `isset()` instead of `empty()` or `if($_POST[val])`

Answer (score -2):

You can use -1 for the default value that represents no amount entry.

Comment: -1 Yikes "-1" is a very valid amount, my bank statement shows that **all** the time.

Comment: lol, it's so funny when somebody does not understand the question/answer, yet he makes smartass comments. -1 can be used IF NO AMOUNT is entered, if the field is blank. Not in the form, of course, but in the database. Then 0 would be just another value.

Comment: Use null for no amount, not -1, bad programming.